# Printing current window to a File/Blob object?

Tags: javascript

I would love to do:

`var file = window.print();`

and `file` being a `File` or `Blob` content of printed document.

The idea behind this is to have my invoices printed to pdf and automatically sent as emails attachments, but my little pinky is telling me I'm a bit demanding today.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to send emails you should be doing it from server-side code, not by trying to get a screen dump of whatever is displayed in the browser.

Comment: is this your website and you want your users to be able to do that?

Comment: @nnnnnn the email is sent from the server. I mentioned that part for context purpose, but I already know how to do this. I'd like to attach pdf to the email though, that pdf being printed on the fly in javascript. The page being printed is an invoice, it's not "whatever is displayed in the browser"

Comment: there is [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to save to pdf, but I don't find it really convenient though.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, I'll definitely take a look at it.

Comment: I said "whatever is displayed in the browser" because *your* phrasing was "printing current window", and you were talking about using `window.print()`. If you want your invoices sent by email you should do all of that server-side.

Comment: @nnnnnn My invoices are generated client side. This question is not about sending emails but how to generate pdf documents from printer to javascript object.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this (see [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45r7yu67/))?

```
var myBlob = new Blob([document.body.textContent], {type : "text/plain"});

var myReader = new FileReader();

myReader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e){
  console.log(e.srcElement.result);
});

//start the reading process.
myReader.readAsText(myBlob);
```

You'd call `window.print` first, and then just create the blob and do with it what you will (perhaps, send the blob in an `XHR` and let your server handle sending the email?)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand. How would `window.print` interact with your reader? I need window.print because it links to a pdf driver, which I hoped would generate a pdf I could use from javascript. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Sebas the save to pdf you've got in the print dialog comes from the os print dialog, I don't think there is any way to access it from js

Comment: Yeah, it's actually Chrome, but I think it's the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

sending an e-mail is responsibility of **server** which you are trying to do from client side. though if you want to save as pdf only then you can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)
here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/)

**html**

```
<div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>a pararaph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

**jquery using jsPDF**

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

Comment: I am not trying to send emails from the client side.